# IIS 7.5 The FastCGI process exited unexpected When Using Oracle

Tags: php, sql, oracle, iis

When I use the following query it works correctly:

---

```
SELECT l.City as TEXT, l.CityId as VALUE FROM MyCity l order by TEXT
```

---

however, if I use:

```
SELECT l.City as TEXT, l.CityId as VALUE, SDO_UTIL.TO_WKTGEOMETRY(SDO_GEOM.SDO_CENTROID(l.SHAPE,0.005)) as GEOM FROM MyCity l order by TEXT
```

I got error IIS 7.5.

The error message is `php-cgi.exe - The FastCGI process exited unexpectedly`.

What went wrong?

Comment: What happens if you execute the second query in another query engine, e.g. SQL*Plus, SQL Developer, TOAD, etc?

Comment: It works in SQL Developer

Comment: check your `php_error.log` file to see the actual php error that's causing it to exit. you can find the location in your `php.ini` but I think the default is in `%TEMP%`

Comment: Solutuon:------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
$db->connect(); --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
$st = $db->DB->prepare($query);--------------------------------------------------
$st->bindColumn(1, $lob, PDO::PARAM_LOB);
$st->execute();



while($row = $st->fetch(PDO::FETCH_BOUND))
{
fpassthru($lob);
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$db->connect(); 
$st = $db->DB->prepare($query);
$st->bindColumn(1, $lob, PDO::PARAM_LOB); 
$st->execute(); 
while($row = $st->fetch(PDO::FETCH_BOUND)) { 
    fpassthru($lob); 
}
```